# TeeChart ActiveX 7 issue

Tags: activex, teechart

I have got an issue in a legacy project that uses TeeChart 7 ActiveX.
Unfortunatelay this project is stuck to this old version.

Is there a real chance to get a fix to be able to run at least the most recent V 7 ocx ?

The issue is: Exporting data from one application as native and importing from another application will cause the importing application to crash. It works once or twice, then this effect happens.

The problem came with version > 7.0.0.6. That means in 7.0.0.6 it works perfect, with higher versions it doesn't.

Comment: We'd be interested to fix the problem in the current version if it's reproducible. Have you tried it? Can you arrange a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Why don't you use v7.0.0.6 if it works fine for you?

Comment: Hello Yeray, thank you for the answer. I've prepared a small project. Can I send this to you per Mail? Or should I provide a downloadlink?

Comment: You can send your project to "info at steema dot com" referencing this question at stackoverflow. If that's a test application, you can also use some online storage giving public access to it (without attaching the .ocx of course).

Answer (score 0):

I have received your project. 
We have sent you an email where we have explained that problem you’re experiencing doesn’t appear in TeeChart Activex v7.0.1.6 published 4 years ago, and neither in TeeChart Activex v2016.0.0.2. Therefore, the problem is fixed for latest Teechart Activex releases and we would like suggest you, update your version to fix it.

Comment: Hello Sandra, I received your mail. Thank you very much. I tested with V 7.0.1.6 but unfortunately the problem still persists.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm aware I simply should consider upgrading my project. Best regards, Tom.